# (Java Swing) How can I use the same radio button in different ButtonsGroups?

Tags: java, swing, radio-button

Suppose I have buttons A and B in panels 1 and 2 like below. How can I group the buttons that only one A and one B can be selected providing that only one button can be selected in a panel?

1 2

A A

B B

Comment: There is no built-in facility for doing this.  You would have to add a listener to each of your buttons.  The question is, what do you expect to happen when the user tries to select more than one button in a single column?  If 1A is selected, and I try to select 1B, does nothing happen?  Does 1A get unselected?  Does 2A then get selected?  What if another row has a selection in column 2?  It can get complex rather quickly, if you have more than two rows and columns.

Comment: Assuming 1A and 2B is selected.Then when I select 1B, I expect that only 1B is selected. I tried adding same radio button in two different buttonGroups but it seems it does not work like that.I was hoping to find a built in function for that.Since there are none i think i will use listeners as you said.Thanks